# MYSQL InnoDB fast delete?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table that continually refreshes with a new set of data.

So, I do a delete from table (everything) and then insert the new set of data.
However the table can never be Without a data set, so I do the above in a transaction.

Everything is wonderful functionally, but the deletes is getting dangerously slow.

Does anyone know of a non-DDL way of speeding up deletes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if creating a second table "nextdataset" and then renaming it would work, I've never tried this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html

Comment: The dropping of the old table would commit my transaction and leave the database integrity questionable until the rename is finished.  
But I am considering using this, as I assume the rename would be very fast... dont think I've ever tested a rename though.

Comment: Ahh, I see you can rename multiple tables atomically :)
I think I can make this work.

Comment: Ah ha, I may have a use for this too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you say something more about the table? (for example contraints, foreign keys, etc.?)

Without any information I would suggest

```
TRUNCATE
```

Here's documentation: [Mysql-Truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)

Comment: Its a plain old no-frills table with only 1 non-unique index on it.
As mentioned in comment on above post, the truncate would commit the transaction halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRUNCATE TABLE` ([MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html))

Comment: +1! This is probably the fastest method, since nothing needs to be selected and than deleted.

Comment: but are TRUNCATEs transaction safe?

Comment: truncates are ddl. They drop and recreate the table .. and implicitly commits, which is no good for me.

Answer (score 0):

run the command **\G SHOW INNODB STATUS** in your mysql monitor when deleting or truncate process operation. 
MyIsam Table is much faster than InnoDB, but no rollBack is possible..